# Laravel collection query: get count only for model with specific property

Tags: php, sql, laravel, database, backend

I have a page where I display a list of projects, including a count of a relationship(rmgs). This is the query:

```
Project::select('id', 'number', 'name', 'status')
                ->withCount(['rmgs as project_rmg_submitted' => static function ($query): void {
                    $query->where('submitted', true);
                }])
                ->withCount(['rmgs as project_rmg_unsubmitted' => static function ($query): void {
                    $query->where('submitted', false);
                }])
                ->get()
```

But I need the count only for projects that have the status='Approved'.

I just found the **[when](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#conditional-clauses)** method, but this check an external flag. I need to check the condition on the model.

```
 Project::select('id', 'number', 'name', 'status')
             --- this should be conditional for project.status='Approved' ----
            ->withCount(['rmgs as project_rmg_submitted' => static function ($query): void {
                $query->where('submitted', true);
            }])
            ->withCount(['rmgs as project_rmg_unsubmitted' => static function ($query): void {
                $query->where('submitted', false);
            }])
             ----------------------------------------------------------
            ->get()
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
Project::select('id', 'number', 'name', 'status')
     
            ->withCount(['rmgs as project_rmg_submitted' => static function ($query): void {
                $query->where('submitted', true);
            }])
            ->withCount(['rmgs as project_rmg_unsubmitted' => static function ($query): void {
                $query->where('submitted', false);
            }])
            ->where('status','=','Approved')
            
            ->get();
```

Comment: I think this will return only the Approved projects right? I need to return all the projects but count the rmgs only for approved projects